# version for the right syntax to use near ' lname LIKE '%dff%'' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a search drop down for a website that can search and narrow down the student searches.  I get the following error in my code:

```
Check the documentation for your version for the right syntax to use near lname LIKE '%dff%'' at line 1
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php

 ob_start();

#Start Session:

session_start();



#Database Connection

include_once('../config/setup.php');



if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ''){
    $s = $_GET['s'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE fName, lName LIKE '%$s%'"; <**--- this where the website detects the error, something about the like query is wrong please help!!**
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,$dbc)){
        $url = $row['fName'];
        $title = $row['lName'];
        echo "<div style='' id='searchtitle'>" . "<a style='font-family:           verdana; text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='$url'>" . $title . "</a>" . "</div>";
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: ..fName like  '%$s%' OR lName like '%$s%'.. (fill in the gaps)

Comment: I did bro and I still have the same error ( You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' lname LIKE '%kdjfksd%'' at line 1)

Comment: `echo  $sql;` post the result

Comment: @Dagon sorry brother I am really new to this this is the first time I use PHP, how would i write that, can you show me the proper syntax pretty please

Comment: `echo $sql;` is the whole proper syntax

Comment: right under $title = $row['lname']; ??  sorry man you must think im slow

Comment: this whole line is wrong `WHERE fName, lName LIKE '%$s%'";` either you remove one, or add a condition for the other. It even tells you where it starts `version for the right syntax to use near ' lname`. Read up on LIKE http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Comment: on the line under `$sql = ..`

Comment: how would write that @Fred-ii-?? sorry this is my first time it is for a project website

Comment: hey @t Fred-ii- I have read about this the % is for a string of 1 or more characters, what this search function does is searches for user names on a college website from the admin side. So the name can range depending what you start searching for. Idk if i am making myself understandable?

Comment: I've posted an answer below to better show you how to use LIKE.

Comment: Putting a _GET variable directly in your SQL is a problem waiting to happen.  Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: @AleksG what do you suggest man? im trying to create a search like google.com which is a drop down search

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query.

Comment: @tadman So what else can I use instead of this $_GET

Comment: You use the `$_GET` in conjunction with `bind_param`. In your query it should be represented as `?` and that gets filled in with the bind call. This makes it very hard to get the escaping wrong if you're disciplined about doing it correctly.

Comment: @tadman sorry I if sound like an idiot but I have no prior experience with this :( can you help me fill it out

Comment: All of this is covered in the [very thorough PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) so you should read through that. Have it bookmarked for easy access, because it usually answers a ton of questions.

Answer (score 5):

Your `where` clause is either missing a parameter, or remove one. This explains the syntax error.

```
WHERE fName, lName LIKE '%$s%'";
      ^^^^^^ // it starts there
```

if you're looking to find if both fName and lName equal your search for, you need to do

```
WHERE fName  LIKE '%$s%' OR lName LIKE '%$s%'";
```

Sidenote: You can replace `OR` by `AND` if you're looking to match both.

or for only one:

```
WHERE fName  LIKE '%$s%'";
```

For more information on LIKE, visit http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/ and its syntax.

Plus, the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Here's another http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Example pulled from ^

```
SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...
WHERE field1 LIKE condition1 [AND [OR]] filed2 = 'somevalue'
```

---

- Then `mysqli_fetch_array($result,$dbc))` remove `,$dbc` from there. DB connection only belongs in your query.

Also, if your query contains a character that MySQL may complain about such as apostrophes and for example `John's place`, then you need to escape your data:

```
$s = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['s']);
```

Using `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()` would signal a syntax error.

Comment: i told em' OR he said no work so ....

Comment: @Dagon `AND` it is then ;-) or their query failed.

Comment: im still waiting for the `echo $sql;`

Comment: it still does not work :( I am going to failllll

Comment: I did both thinks fred I put AND because were are trying to enable a search function that searches by either first name or last name :(

Comment: unescaped input and he's inputtinh in a ' ?

Comment: please `echo $sql` and past it

Comment: just did @dagon still getting the same error msg ima just give up ill fail :(

Comment: the point is to show US what you have - so we can debug it

Comment: <?php

ob_start();

#Start Session:

session_start();



#Database Connection

include_once('../config/setup.php');



if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ''){
 $s = $_GET['s'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Searchtitle LIKE '%$s%'";
 echo $sql;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,$dbc)){
  $url = $row['fName'];
  $title = $row['lName'];
  echo "<div style='' id='searchtitle'>" . "<a style='font-family: verdana; text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='$url'>" . $title . "</a>" . "</div>";
 }

}
 

?>

Comment: how i post the code but it looks messy

Comment: i just wanted to see the query that `echo $sql` returned.

Comment: same exact thing, same error message after I uploaded to the server

Comment: its the querry producing the error, the actual query we have yet to actually see so um - oh i quit,

Comment: @dagon thanks for the effort anyhow !

Comment: sorry I wasn't here to try and help, Hydro went out soon after I posted my answer. @Bruno Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Bruno then this `mysqli_fetch_array($result,$dbc))` remove `,$dbc` from there. It's in my answer now.